# Is there a way to create multiple tags using the buildx build command in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit, buildx

I am trying to use the `docker buildx build` command and I would like to be able to create multiple tags in one line.  An example of what I have tried

```
docker buildx build . \
    --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64 \
    --no-cache --push \
    -t test:latest -t test:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
```

I have seen this issue, but I haven't been able to get it to work
https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/396

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works exactly as you've posted with multiple `-t` args, e.g. `-t repo1:tag1 -t repo2:tag2`:

```
$ regctl tag ls sudobmitch/demo
alpine
regcli-test
regctl
ubuntu

$ docker buildx build -f build/Dockerfile.regctl.buildkit -t sudobmitch/demo:regctl1 -t sudobmitch/demo:regctl2 --push .
[+] Building 13.4s (24/24) FINISHED                                                                          
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.regctl.buildkit                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 4.40kB                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 172B                                                                       0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                              0.3s
 => [auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                        0.0s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:443aab4ca21183e069e7d8b2dc68006594f40bd  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:443aab4ca21183e069e7d8b2dc68006594f40bddf1b15bbd83  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.17-alpine                                   0.4s
 => [auth] library/golang:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                           0.0s
 => [golang 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.17-alpine@sha256:3bdce0a4828648811dc3ac155b8f5155ca6e  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/golang:1.17-alpine@sha256:3bdce0a4828648811dc3ac155b8f5155ca6e13c5a86  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                       0.2s
 => => transferring context: 8.95MB                                                                     0.2s
 => CACHED [golang 2/4] RUN apk add --no-cache       ca-certificates       git       make               0.0s
 => CACHED [golang 3/4] RUN addgroup -g 1000 appuser  && adduser -u 1000 -G appuser -D appuser  && mkd  0.0s
 => CACHED [golang 4/4] WORKDIR /src                                                                    0.0s
 => [dev 1/1] COPY --link . /src/                                                                       0.3s
 => [build 1/1] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=gomod,target=/go/pkg/mod/cache     --mount=type=cache,id=gor  1.5s
 => CACHED [release-scratch 1/5] ADD  --link build/root.tgz /                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [release-scratch 2/5] COPY --link --from=build /etc/passwd /etc/group /etc/                  0.0s
 => CACHED [release-scratch 3/5] COPY --link --from=build /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/  0.0s
 => CACHED [release-scratch 4/5] COPY --link --from=build --chown=1000:1000 /home/appuser/ /home/appus  0.0s
 => [release-scratch 5/5] COPY --link --from=build /src/bin/regctl /regctl                              0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                  3.7s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                 0.4s
 => => exporting manifest sha256:ebd28e5f9096008ce106880bea389dfaf164cd298429705ccb922fd72142f83c       0.0s
 => => exporting config sha256:5fc50e1c198eb9061de9f0c1a12cb660753c41b46d1eb73f6117e3e260ba641d         0.0s
 => => pushing layers                                                                                   0.2s
 => => pushing manifest for docker.io/sudobmitch/demo:regctl1@sha256:ebd28e5f9096008ce106880bea389dfaf  0.2s
 => => pushing manifest for docker.io/sudobmitch/demo:regctl2@sha256:ebd28e5f9096008ce106880bea389dfaf  0.1s
 => [auth] sudobmitch/demo:pull,push token for registry-1.docker.io                                     0.0s
 => [auth] sudobmitch/demo:pull,push token for registry-1.docker.io                                     0.0s
 => [auth] sudobmitch/demo:pull,push token for registry-1.docker.io                                     0.0s
 => [auth] sudobmitch/demo:pull,push token for registry-1.docker.io                                     0.0s

$ regctl tag ls sudobmitch/demo
alpine
regcli-test
regctl
regctl1
regctl2
ubuntu
```

This is assuming `test` was an example in your question. If you actually tried to push to the `test` repo, that expands to Docker Hub's Library, along side other official images like `alpine`, `busybox`, `debian`, etc. You don't have access to push there, so make sure to point to a repository where you have access to push images and have logged in.

Comment: Yes, 'test' was an example.  Thanks, I am going to rearrange the command a little.